# Есть ли библиотека для распознавания рукописного текста по типу shiftlab_ocr?

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание-символов

Есть библиотека shiftlab_ocr и я написал код:

```
from shiftlab_ocr.doc2text.reader import Reader
from PIL import Image
local_filename = 'img.jpg'

image = Image.open(local_filename)

reader = Reader()

result = reader.doc2text(local_filename)

print(result[0])
```

но он выдаёт ошибку. Я перепробовал уже всё
Ошибка

Comment: А тесеракт не пробовали? Не знаю насколько хорошо он рукописные тексты распознает, но при желании можно дообучить.

Comment: Ошибка, о которой вы пишете, должна быть приведена прямо в вопросе, в текстовом виде и целиком. По пересказам ошибок диагностика невозможна.